# What is the purpose of (<$) in the Functor class?

Tags: haskell, functor

The `Functor` class contains a hidden second member:

```
class Functor f where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
  (GHC.Base.<$) :: a -> f b -> f a
```

Documentation:

> Replace all locations in the input with the same value. The default definition is `fmap . const`, but this may be overridden with a more efficient version.

I would like to know more. Why this `fmap . const` idiom is a separate member? How an alternative implementation might be more efficient? What are applications of this combinator?

Comment: Essentially, you might have a more efficient use case. If you do not, you leave it default. It means you only care about structure, not value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is included as a member to allow users to customize it for speed, and I guess because it makes it consistent with `>>`.

I think it might be faster in the cases of the reader monad `((->) r)`.

```
x <$ _ = const x
```

vs

```
x <$ fa = fmap (const x) fa = (const x) . fa
```

although, this is really a question of compiler optimization.  And, it does not appear to be defined for the reader monad in base.

It also might lead to a performance boost in strict collections.  Namely

```
data Strict a = Strict !a

instance Functor Strict where
   fmap f (Strict a) = Strict (f a)
   x <$ _ = Strict x
```

this does not obey the functor laws, but nonetheless, you might want to do this in some situations.

A third example comes from infinite collections.  Consider infinite lists

```
data Long a = Cons a (Long a)

instance Functor Long where
  fmap f (Cons x xs) = Cons (f x) (fmap f xs)
```

which works fine, but think about

```
countUpFrom x = Cons x (countUpFrom (x+1))
ones = 1 <$ (countUpFrom 0)
```

now, with our definition that will expand to

```
ones = 1 <$ (countUpFrom 0)
   = fmap (const 1) (countUpFrom 0) 
   = Cons (const 1 0) (fmap (const 1) (countUpFrom 1)
   = Cons (const 1 0) (Cons (const 1 1) (fmap (const 1) (countUpFrom 2))
```

that is, it will allocate a whole bunch of `Cons` cells as you walk this list.  While, on the other hand, if you defined

```
x <$ _ = let xs = Cons x xs in xs
```

than

```
ones = 1 <$ countUpFrom 0
 = let xs = Cons 1 xs in xs
```

which has tied the knot.  An even more extreme example comes with infinite trees

```
data ITree a = ITree a (ITree a) (ITree a)
```

Comment: You seemed to have flipped `<$` to `$>` in the second half of your answer. Typo?

Comment: @dbaupp: I assumed so, so I just went ahead and fixed it.

Comment: @dbaupp thanks, I had done that.  Part of the reason I like strongly typed languages is they help catch errors like that.

Answer (score 12):

Another example of `<$` usage:

Suppose you have a parser functor `P`, and `parser :: P A`.

`f <$> parser` means that you need to parse something and then apply `f` to the result.

`a <$ parser` means that you don't need to parse anything (you're not interested in the result) — you only need to *recognize*, which can be much faster.

See e.g. the [regex-applicative](https://github.com/feuerbach/regex-applicative/blob/master/Text/Regex/Applicative/Interface.hs) library (pay attention to the usage of the `Void` constructor).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a couple code snippets from something I'm currently writing that might give you an idea of what you'd use this combinator for:

```
pPrimType = choice
    [ WIPrimIntType <$> flag "unsigned" <*> pIntTypeSize
    , WIPrimFloatType <$> flag "unrestricted" <*> pFloatTypeSize
    , WIPrimBoolType <$ "boolean"
    , WIPrimByteType <$ "byte"
    , WIPrimOctetType <$ "octet"
    ]

pConst = WIConst 
     <$  "const"
     <*> pConstType
     <*> pIdent
     <*  "="
     <*> pConstValue
     <*  semicolon
```

If the string literals look weird it's because I have `OverloadedStrings` enabled and those are being converted into parsers that match a string while doing a few other things (eating whitespace, checking for token boundaries, &c.)

It seems pretty trivial, but honestly it makes `Applicative`-y parser definitions a *lot* more readable when you lead with a parser that doesn't produce a value you care about, like required keywords and such. Otherwise you have to introduce a bunch of extra `pure`s or weird parentheses or other distracting noise.

As for why it's part of the type class, the usual reason for adding an otherwise superfluous function to a type class is the expectation that some instances will be able to optimize it, e.g. `(>>)`. Since the efficiency difference depends on the instance (that's the whole point!) there's no single answer there. I can't immediately think of any obvious instances where it would make a major difference, though.